# Why my database is not working, I am using ways in official documentation?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

**I have a problem:** Firebase Database is not working and I cannot understand why that happened (cannot post data to server, when I press button to send data- nothing happens, data does not saving in server).

**Look my code:**

```
private var db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()                                               
private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference                                           

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {                                          
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)                                                        
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)                                                    
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)                                                              

 dbReference = db.reference.child("member")                                                

 add_item_to_db_button.setOnClickListener {                                                 
     dbReference.push()                                                                    
         .setValue(Member(item_name.text.toString(), item_description.text.toString()))    

 }                                                                                         
}
```

**My constructor class to send data to a database:**

```
 class Member {
 lateinit var itemName: String
 lateinit var itemDescription: String

constructor()
constructor(itemName: String, itemDescription: String) {
    this.itemName = itemName
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription
  }

}
```

My dependencies(`google()` and `jcenter()` Is enabled in top-level `Gradle`):

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My `XML` file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:padding="40dp"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:src="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <EditText
    android:text="Name of product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_description"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_item_to_db_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And finally, database rules:**

```
"rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
 }
```

I'm do not understand why db is not working. Tried several ways was posted in `StackOverflow` - does not help.

Comment: wat is not working

Comment: Sorry, I m updated a question. Data does not posting to database. After button clicks - nothing happens.

Comment: Is your project connected to firebase?

Comment: Sure. I am connected my project.

Comment: You sure you are not missing `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` ? If you are then just paste it as first line inside `OnCreate` or in Application Class .

Comment: Can you try this?
dbReference.setValue(Member(item_name.text.toString(), item_description.text.toString()))

Comment: Sec, I`ll try it

Comment: Sorry, does not helped.

Comment: Can you try this please?
dbReference = db.getReference.child("member")   instead of dbReference = db.reference.child("member")

Comment: Tried. `reference` in Kotlin using instead `getReference()` \ `setReference()`.

Comment: My last idea is you should use this code in onCreate method.

private var db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

Comment: Tried. Does not helps.

Comment: First, stop ignoring potential errors. Try to attach a listener to the set value operation, do you get something printed out in the logcat? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Check what unique id is generated on push and if it is successful the post data
Even if saveValue fails you debug with the key
ex 
DatabaseReference pushedPostRef = postsRef.push();
// Get the unique ID generated by a push()
String postId = pushedPostRef.getKey();

Comment: Also as you are using dbReference.push().setValue add an onCompleteListener to see if the call is successful.

Comment: @Build3r, ok I`ll try it.

Comment: Have you tried to view your database from your project console? I've been having this same issue from my web app for the past 5 hours. I cannot even see my data on my project database console

Comment: @sudo_kaizen, yes, I am checking all updates in console.

Comment: Try adding completiong listeners and log the results to get more context:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all people who tryied to help me - thank you a lot ;) In my case all ways does not helped me, so Im tryied to connect `Firebase DB` to another `Google account` and then connect `Firebase Database`, result - all is working good.

Answer (score 0):

You need valid network and this permission in your manifest files. Cross check in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Sorry, does not helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to a data class:

```
data class Member(val itemName : String, val itemDescription : String) {
constructor() : this("", "")
}
```

Comment: Tried. Does not helps. In this case, very interesting situation, because im in previous project use constructor similar to what I have at the moment, and all was worked nice.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem. But can't find a permanent solution.
From firebase community I got a mail.

We have been receiving several reports of the same issue with different ISP providers in India, however this is an issue with the network of the ISPs which is out of our reach and control, nonetheless we are working with local providers to try to restore the services as soon as possible, for that we are gathering as much information as possible on the issue so we would appreciate if you provide us the name of your ISP.

We would recommend reaching out your ISP to request further details and information on the troubleshooting to find the root cause for this issue as we can confirm the problem is not on our side.

Apologies for not being able to further assist you with this but be sure that we are still working to have it back up and running.